# C++ General Errors Classes Constructors

Tags: c++

I have a two classes and a main. I have followed everything as best as I can find but still have errors

Any help identify the error would be well received

[Error Message here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVpUq.png)

main.cpp

```
#include "People.h"
#include "Birthday.h"

int main()
{
    Birthday birthObject(8, 7, 1987);

    birthObject.printDate();

    People danielGadd("DanielGadd", birthObject);

    danielGadd.printInfo();

    return 0;
}
```

People.h

```
#ifndef PEOPLE_H
#define PEOPLE_H
#include <string>
#include "Birthday.h"

class People
{
public:
    People(std::string x, Birthday b);
    void printInfo();

private:
    std::string name;
    Birthday dateOfBirth;
};

#endif // PEOPLE_H
```

People.cpp

```
#include "People.h"
#include "Birthday.h"

People::People(std::string x, Birthday b)
    : name(x), dateOfBirth(b)
{
}

void People::printInfo() {
    std::cout << name << " was born on ";
    dateOfBirth.printDate();
}
```

Birthday.h

```
#ifndef BIRTHDAY_H
#define BIRTHDAY_H
#include <iostream>

class Birthday
{
public:
    Birthday(int d, int m, int y);
    void printDate();
private:
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};

#endif //BIRTHDAY_H
```

Birthday.cpp

```
#include "Birthday.h"

Birthday::Birthday(int d, int m, int y)
{
    day = d;
    month = m;
    year = y;
}


void Birthday::printDate()
{
    std::cout << day << "/" << month << "/" << year << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: please include the error messages in the question (plain text, no image)

Comment: If this is Visual Studio copy the text of the error message from the Output Tab. `Alt-2`

Comment: is this a copy-paste mistake, or is there a second declaration of `class Birthday` in your Birthday.cpp ?

Comment: remove the `using namespace std;` and write `std::string` instead of `string` and `std::cout` / `std::endl` instead of `cout` / `endl`. This should fix already some of the errors (if not all).

Comment: Yes added Error Image. Let me try your proposed changes

Comment: I used all your notes and revised my question above. It still has error messages. I added the image above also displaying the error message

Comment: It compiles when I use `cl main.cpp Birthday.cpp People.cpp /EHsc`, so this would now appear to be a problem with the IDE, not the code itself.

Comment: Yes I decided after reading another review, to copy and paste code, while deleting files. Re make the file and paste. Virtual Studio 2015 IDE. Then it worked. Seems to be like the file goes messed up with endless possibilities. So all works now it seems. 
I have to say again thanks very much for your time. Its so remarkable how this sites help, and the people who give time to do thing like try compile and help and stuff. 
I look forward to getting to a level where I can come on here and contribute back.
Thanks Justin Time and Tobi

Answer (score 0):

I am using Virtual Studio 2015. I found solution. I simple deleted the People.exe from debug folder and built project again. And it worked.
Al;so similar problem I deleted the file and re made it. Pasted same code in and it fixed issue. No idea why